# Every time I try to run this program I get this error message for the code below. How can I fix it so it runs in its entirety?

Tags: timeout, thread-sleep

timeoutRemaining = round(timeout - diff, 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

# start all the threads
    for i in range(totalMethods):
        threads[i].start()

```
diff = time.time() - startTime
timeoutRemaining = round(timeout - diff, 0)

# sleep for timeout
time.sleep(timeoutRemaining)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typing issue.  Make sure you are performing math on arithmetic types.

In other words 'startTime' (a str) is not a float.